Can the naïve version of Cantor's diagonal argument fail to find a number not on the list?
I was looking at a question here
How to resolve this paradox involving Cantor's diagonal argument?
This question was resolved by noticing that $1/9$ does not follow the pattern implied by the set that preceded it.
I am certain that there is some reason why we can't just add $1/9$ to the set and then sort the elements from smallest to largest.
The normal version of Cantor's diagonal argument relies on a naïve definition of set and list.
If we were to model a list of numbers after my shopping list, then we could make the elements smaller and smaller as we go down the list.
Assume that we have a normal sheet of paper and we are going to fill the top 20.0 cm with our infinite list by cutting our font size in half at every step, then we will get a list like this. (We will use binary numbers)
At 0.0 cm we will write $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{red}{0}$ binary for 0/1 
At 10.0 cm we will write $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{blue}{1}$$\color{red}{0}$ binary for 1/2 
At 15.0 cm we will write $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{blue}{11}$$\color{red}{0}$ binary for 3/4  
At 17.5 cm we will write $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{blue}{111}$$\color{red}{0}$ binary for 7/8  
At 18.75 cm we will write $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{blue}{1111}$$\color{red}{0}$ binary for 15/16  
$\dots$ 
Generally at cm = $20-\frac{20}{2^n}$ Write = $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ as  $n = 0 \to \infty $
$\dots$ 
All the infinite amount of entries will come before 20.0 cm, allowing us to write  $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{blue}{111 \dots}$ at 20.0 cm.
We can take the diagonal $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{red}{000 \dots}$ flip all the digits and get $\color{red}{0}$.$\color{blue}{111 \dots}$
And that number will be on the list at 20.0 cm down.
If this argument is just the result of naïve definitions of the diagonal argument, can we formalise the argument to avoid such things?

Adding a number does not change anything because you can add this number to the list (say at the first position) and apply Cantor's diagonal argument again. No matter how often you add a number , you cannot fill out the gap.

There are lots of binary strings with infinitely many $1's$.  Just adding one of them to the list, doesn't get all of them.

It should be mentioned that this method does not work in pratice anyway. We neither can write down a list of infinite many numbers , nor can we even write down the full decimal expansion of a number (assuming it has infinite many zeros at the end in the case of termination). The "diagonal" is therefore infinite long and it does not help to compare it with the finite case of $n$ numbers with length $n$. This is the reason why so many people have difficulties to understand this method.

$0.\overline{1}$ is not in your original list. There's no "infinity-th" place to put it. Once you add it to the list somewhere, the diagonal argument will now produce a different number with a zero somewhere.

For example if you put $0.1\overline{1}$ in the first position and shift everything else accordingly, then the diagonal argument will now produce $0.0\overline{1}$, which wasn't in that list, either. The subtle place your argument breaks down is that there is no way to "sort in least-to-greatest order" the set $A={ 0,0.1,0.11,... } \cup { 0.\overline{1} }$. Here "sort in least-to-greatest order" means "define an increasing function $f : \mathbb{N} \to A$."

Regarding "add $1/9$ to the set and then sort the elements from smallest to largest." When you do this, $1/9$ will appear after all other elements. This new (type of) list, is not a list in which positions are indexed by natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Instead, the positions can be indexed by $\mathbb{N}\cup{\infty}$, where $\infty$ is a new element that is larger than all of those in $\mathbb{N}$. This is fine, but falls outside of the assumptions in Cantor's argument. In it, it is an assumption that the "list" is ordered as in $\mathbb{N}$.

Voting to close. The normal version of Cantor's diagonal argument does not rely "on a naïve defintion of set and list". The comments have pointed out several errors in your argument, which is therefore based more on straight-up misunderstandings rather than "just ... naïve definitions".

You said "I am certain that there is some reason why we can't just add 1/9 to the set and then sort the elements from smallest to largest."
First off, assume you can "sort the elements" of the set of all reals "from largest to smallest." That means that for any two consecutive real numbers in your sorted list, call them r(n) and r(n+1), there is no real number whose value is between them. But [r(n)+r(n+1)]/2 is between them. This paradox proves that you can't make that sorted list. And this is actually how Cantor's first proof that the reals are not countable worked, although it was a bit more complicated.
But the real problem with your argument is that adding the "found" number to the list does not change anything. And the reason many people think it might, is that they were taught a subtly incorrect version of the diagonalization argument. Here is a rough outline that corrects it, even if it is not as rigorous as it could be:

Let R1 be the set of all real numbers between 0 and 1, inclusive. This is sometimes written [0,1].
Let r(1), r(2), r(3), ... , r(n), ... be any infinite list of real numbers in R1. Please note that I did not say all real numbers in R1. That is not part of the proof, yet.
Construct another real number, r0, by making its nth digit different from the nth digit of r(n) (and not a "9", btw). So r0 is different from r(n) for every n. It is not in your list.
But r0 is a real number between 0 and 1, so it is an element of R1.
This proves the proposition "For any list of real numbers in R1, there is a real number r0, that is in R1, but is not in the list.
Here I'm going to quote Cantor as closely as I can: "From this proposition it follows immediately that the totality of all elements of R1 cannot be put into a list, otherwise we would have the contradiction, that the number r0 would be both an element of R1, but also not an element of R1.

Seen this way, it is clear that adding the missing number to the list is irrelevant. The point is not to contradict an assumption that you were incorrectly taught occurs in step 2, that all numbers were listed. It is to prove that any list has to be incomplete. And since any list has to be incomplete, no list can be complete.

Thank you for your reply. We are not trying to sort or list the real numbers. We are only listing the set from the link in the original post. Read the question again, we are creating a list that has all the elements of the set {1-1/2^n} where n=0 to infinity. Then the last element on the list will be 0.111... And only then will we look for the diagonal which will be 0.000... then flip it and get 0.111... which is on the list. Since the set has cardinality of aleph 0 that is not so strange.

" Then the last element on the list will be 0.111... " Please think about this claim, with the intent to find what might possibly be wrong with it. Hint: Every element in the set of all natural numbers is a finite number. But the set itself has an infinite number of elements.

Every element on the list (that comes before the 20cm line) will have a finite string of 1’s (one more than the previous element) followed by one or more 0's. There will be an infinite amount of these elements. Then below the 20cm line will be one element with an infinite string of 1’s. This one element will be the last element on the list.

This is just Zeno's paradox. You will never reach the 20 cm line, let alone have a string below it. AGAIN: Every string in your list - all above 20 cm - will have a finite number of ones and an infinite number of zeros. If you want to argue that, tell me what natural number (and "infinity" isn't a natural number) corresponds to 20 cm.

Yes, an infinite number of zeros is one or more zeros. And no natural number would correspond to 20 cm. But there is no reason that you can't write the 0.999... below the 20 cm line, and if you use a standard size paper you can write it 21 cm down the list, all it needs to be is on the page below the infinite list of 0.999...000... elements and it will be the last element on the list. That is why we need to pull out the rule book and read the fine print on the axiom of infinity.

"There is no reason that you can't write the 0.999... below the 20 cm line." Sure there is. IT IS NOT IN YOUR PROGRESSION.

We are not making a progression. We are making a list. We can put anything we want on our list, it just happens that the top of the list has an infinite progression. Below that we could list all the states in the union or anything. It is just a list. You are imposing an unnecessary condition.

Yes, you are making a progression. You even defined it: "We will get a list like this. ... Generally at cm = 20−20/2^n Write = 1−1/2^n." You don't seem to understand that "as n=0→∞" does not mean that n ever equals ∞. In fact, it can't, since ∞ is not a number. That's the reason Cantor never used it as a number. Cantor Diagonalization does not prove, by itself, that his set can't be put into a bijection with the naturlal numbers. It proves that any list you have is missing one. You tried to define one, but it never includes the string "11111...".

BUT, if you want to include "11111..." Somewhere in your list? Say, at line m? Then Cantor's anti-diagonal has a zero in column m. You can't get around this. ANY LIST YOU CONSTRUCT can be used to construct an anti-diagonal that is not in that list.

Our list is a 28cm paper. It has a progression that ends as close to 20cm as possible without touching it. The diagonal also ends as close to 20cm as possible. 0.999... is 21cm down. The diagonal will not touch the 21cm mark on the list, thus we do get around this.

You list is on a 28cm paper. It has a progression that DOES NOT END. Until you can understand that, you have no business trying to discuss Cantor's Diagonal Argument, or anything having to do with the infinite sets.

I think of our progression as an eternal static object, but you seem to think it is a forever growing in time and space construct. If it does not end at the 20cm line, then where would it end? I don't know what the axioms say about this. Even Zeno's paradox has an end.

"If it does not end at the 20cm line, then where would it end?"  ????? An infinite sequence is one that does not have an end. Yours does not ever reach the 20 cm line, it just keeps getting closer by half the distance. See Zeno's Paradox. And again, until you grasp this concept, you have no business trying to discuss Cantor's Diagonal Argument, or anything having to do with the infinite sets.

"See Zeno's Paradox." At every step Zeno halved the distance but he also halved the time it takes to cover the distance so he was able find the end. https://youtu.be/dKSlOgARvrs?si=Lr_jsBQm3SdaVjiI

"So he was able find the end." Was he? How many intervals did it take? And please note that "infinity" is not a natural number. What that video showed, was that when BOTH distance and time get halved in each iteration, that the UNENDING sequence of intervals has a mathematical limit. Your UNENDING progression does not have that property. And I hate to sound like a broken record, but until you grasp this concept, you have no business trying to discuss Cantor's Diagonal Argument.

"sound like a broken record" Thank you for your time and patience, I do understand that this sounds strange and different. It did to me too.

It took an infinite number of intervals. I don't understand why it needs to be a finite natural number of intervals. You did say that the sequence would never reach the 20cm line, so the diagonal will never reach 20cm and be "contaminated" by the 0.111... at 21cm down the list. Therefore it is possible to find the anti-diagonal on the list, it is at the 21cm line.

Now you are just talking nonsense, and it demonstrates how badly you want your conclusion to be true despite all the facts that prove it isn't. Every element of your list can be associated with a (finite) natural number n. This is why it "needs to be a finite number of intervals." The nth element of your list is at (20 cm) - (20) * 2^(-n) cm. Please tell me, for what value of n does this equal 21 cm?

"needs to be a finite number of intervals." Imagine an infinite long line divided into 1mm intervals, every one of those intervals can be associated with a finite natural number, yet we have an infinite number of intervals. So it is possible to have an infinite number of intervals, with a natural number associated with each interval.

(continued) Our progression is such an object, and it is above the 20cm line. The singleton element 0.999... is not in the progression, but it is on the list at 21cm. You are a bit ahead of me when you imply that a natural number needs to be associated with every element on the list. We will do that with Hilbert's hotel. We will move all the residents in the progression to an even numbered room.

(continued) We will change our progression to (20 cm) - (20) * 2^((n-2)/2) where n is the set of even numbers n = 2 -> infinity. Then we can associate 3 to the 0.999... in the row at the 21cm line on the list. Then all the elements on our list will be mapped to a natural number.

"So it is possible to have an infinite number of intervals, with a natural number associated with each interval." Yes, it is. And every one of those infinitely-many natural numbers has a finite value. Every one of your lines is above the 20 cm line, at (20 cm) - (20) * 2^(-n) cm. There is no line at 21 cm.
